# Websockets not supported on blocking connectors

Tags: java, websocket, jetty

Im made websocket server. its work on localhost, but when I deploy it to server, I get error. I can not find a solution. On localhost I using gwt server embleded for jetty 8.1.7. on deployment server have too jetty 8.1.7.

```
public abstract class WebSocketServlet extends org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketServlet implements TextMessageHandler {

private final HashMap<Integer, Socket> sockets = new HashMap<Integer, Socket>();

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    if ("WebSockets".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getHeader("Upgrade"))) {
        String origin = request.getHeader("Origin");
        if (origin == null) {
            origin = request.getHeader("Sec-WebSocket-Origin");
        }
        if (!checkOrigin(request, origin)) {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
            return;
        }
    }
    getServletContext().getNamedDispatcher("default").forward(request, response);
}

public WebSocket doWebSocketConnect(HttpServletRequest request, String protocol) {
    String[] s = request.getPathInfo().split("/");
    String ss = (s.length>1?s[1]:"default");
    return new Socket(this, ss);
}

public void send(int token, String message) throws IOException,   InvalidTokenException {
    Socket socket = sockets.get(token);
    if (socket == null) {
        throw new InvalidTokenException();
    }
    sockets.get(token).sendMessage(message);
}

public boolean isOpened(int token) throws InvalidTokenException {
    Socket socket = sockets.get(token);
    if (socket == null) {
        throw new InvalidTokenException();
    }
    return sockets.get(token).isOpen();
}

public class InvalidTokenException extends Exception {
};

class Socket implements WebSocket.OnTextMessage {
    private Connection _connection;
    private TextMessageHandler handler;
    private String channel;

    public Socket(TextMessageHandler handler, String channel) {
        this.handler = handler;
        this.channel = channel;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClose(int closeCode, String message) {
        sockets.remove(this._connection.hashCode());
        handler.onClose(_connection.hashCode(), channel);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(String data) {
        handler.onMessage(_connection.hashCode(), channel, data);
    }

    public void sendMessage(String data) throws IOException {
        _connection.sendMessage(data);
    }

    public boolean isOpen() {
        return _connection.isOpen();
    }

    @Override
    public void onOpen(Connection connection) {
        sockets.put(connection.hashCode(), this);
        _connection = connection;
        handler.onJoin(connection.hashCode(), channel);
    }
}
}
```

web.xml

```
<!-- Servlets -->
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>wsservlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.mostka.server.WsServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>wsservlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/socket/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

start.xml

```
etc/jetty-jmx.xml
etc/jetty.xml
etc/jetty-ajp.xml
etc/jetty-hightide.xml
# etc/jetty-ssl.xml
# etc/jetty-requestlog.xml
etc/jetty-deploy.xml
#etc/jetty-overlay.xml
etc/jetty-webapps.xml
etc/jetty-contexts.xml
etc/jetty-testrealm.xml
etc/jetty-jaas.xml
```

jetty.xml

```
    <Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">

        <!-- =========================================================== -->
        <!-- Server Thread Pool                                          -->
        <!-- =========================================================== -->
        <Set name="ThreadPool">
          <!-- Default queued blocking threadpool -->
          <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool">
            <Set name="minThreads">10</Set>
            <Set name="maxThreads">200</Set>
            <Set name="detailedDump">false</Set>
          </New>
        </Set>

        <!-- =========================================================== -->
        <!-- Set connectors                                              -->
        <!-- =========================================================== -->

        <Call name="addConnector">
          <Arg>
              <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                <Set name="host"><Property name="jetty.host" /></Set>
                <Set name="port"><Property name="jetty.port" default="9627"/></Set>
                <Set name="maxIdleTime">300000</Set>
                <Set name="Acceptors">2</Set>
                <Set name="statsOn">false</Set>
                <Set name="confidentialPort">9626</Set>
            <Set name="lowResourcesConnections">20000</Set>
            <Set name="lowResourcesMaxIdleTime">5000</Set>
              </New>
          </Arg>
        </Call>

        <!-- =========================================================== -->
        <!-- Set handler Collection Structure                            -->
        <!-- =========================================================== -->
        <Set name="handler">
          <New id="Handlers" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection">
            <Set name="handlers">
             <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler">
               <Item>
                 <New id="Contexts" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection"/>
               </Item>
               <Item>
                 <New id="DefaultHandler" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler"/>
               </Item>
             </Array>
            </Set>
          </New>
        </Set>

        <!-- =========================================================== -->
        <!-- extra options                                               -->
        <!-- =========================================================== -->
        <Set name="stopAtShutdown">true</Set>
        <Set name="sendServerVersion">true</Set>
        <Set name="sendDateHeader">true</Set>
        <Set name="gracefulShutdown">1000</Set>
        <Set name="dumpAfterStart">false</Set>
        <Set name="dumpBeforeStop">false</Set>

    </Configure>
```

error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Websockets not supported on blocking connectors
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketFactory.upgrade(WebSocketFactory.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketFactory.acceptWebSocket(WebSocketFactory.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketServlet.service(WebSocketServlet.java:104)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
```

full error stack http://sharetext.org/xr5i

client sended header

Request

```
URL:ws://gwtver.jvmhost.net/socket/testChannel/a?key=123
Request Headersview source
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:Upgrade
Host:gwtver.jvmhost.net
Origin:http://gwtver.jvmhost.net
Pragma:no-cache
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions:x-webkit-deflate-frame
Sec-WebSocket-Key:O0QbqSZsNjKvMfdcElXbNQ==
Sec-WebSocket-Version:13
Upgrade:websocket
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36
Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
key:123
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct.  WebSocket does not support Blocking Connectors.

This is mainly due to the nature of the Protocol and the API as developed.

It would be wise to switch from Blocking connectors to SelectChannel connectors now, as all future versions of Jetty have eliminated Blocking connectors entirely.

The pressures of new protocols (SPDY, WebSocket, HTTP/2.0), new APIs (javax.websocket, Java EE 7), and updated Servlet specs (Async I/O), has essentially eliminated the possibility of using Blocking connectors.

Comment: Thanks. But how I can change blocked connector? and why is working on one server and on other is not working witch same wersion and same code?
Im not realy sure if Im good test it second time on same 9.1.7 server, but on 9.1.11 is working.